# Scroll listener - first distanceY always negative for downward scroll?

Tags: android

I've got a GestureDetector.OnGestureListener hooked up to a ListView. I'm trying to listen for scroll events when the user is scrolling down:

```
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    }
}
```

But I see a very strange stream of "distanceY" values:

```
distanceY: -417.02252  // <-- huh?
e1: null
e2: MotionEvent{4097ac08 action=2 x=233.6657 y=417.02252 pressure=0.79999995 size=0.33333334}

distanceY: 1.5640259
e1: null
e2: MotionEvent{4097ac08 action=2 x=233.6657 y=415.4585 pressure=0.79999995 size=0.33333334}

distanceY: 1.5640259
e1: null
e2: MotionEvent{4097ac08 action=2 x=233.6657 y=413.89447 pressure=0.79999995 size=0.40000004}

... rest of values are positive, as expected ...
```

The first "distanceY" value is negative (unexpected), but then subsequent ones are all positive. What could explain this? I can reproduce this behavior each time.

Thanks

Comment: great question. I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distanceY` is the distance between current and previous `onScroll` event. Since this is the first such event I'm assuming it starts calculating from zero.

```
distanceY: ____-417.02252____  // Same value as...
e1: null
e2: MotionEvent{4097ac08 action=2 x=233.6657 y=____417.02252____ // ...here...
```

Comment: That makes sense, but from output above, is there any way to detect that condition? For example, I'd like to discard that one event, but there's no way to tell if it's just the first one or not.

Comment: I would expect both ``distanceX`` and ``distanceY`` are negative ``MotionEvent`` ``x`` and ``y`` values. Checking if both sums are below some very small error margin close to zero (or sum equals zero) would give rather good probability for skipping the first ``onScroll`` event. This is best I can think of.

Comment: In the end I just set up my own logic in a touch listener to deal with this. Very frustrating that they call you back with those values.

Comment: Can you tell me how you made it? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

But in my case I use different OnGestureListener-s for onInterceptTouchEvent(...) and onTouchEvent(...) methods.

Therefore I just set a flag in intercept-listener for ignoring first scroll event passed to actual touch-event-listener

```
private class GestureInterceptListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        final boolean shouldIntercept = ...; // here we decide should we intercept this event, or should it be passed further 
        if (shouldIntercept) {
            mGestureProcessListener.setFirstScrollEventIgnored(true);
        }
        return shouldIntercept;
    }

}


private class GestureProcessListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private boolean ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = false;

    /**
     * For some reason first scroll event on half-visible settings list gets strange incorrect negative values
     * @param isIgnored - should next scroll event be ignored? value resets to false afterwards
     */
    public void setFirstScrollEventIgnored(boolean isIgnored) {
        ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = isIgnored;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent) {
            ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = false;
            return true;
        }
        ... // process scroll event here
        return true;
    }

}
```

Works for me