# Android onScroll event giving bad values

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to implement a custom 2-way scroll with the Android canvas and a `GuestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` but I'm having some issues. It seems like the first scroll event with it always gives a huge inaccurate jump.

For example, if I click in the middle of the canvas and scroll a tiny bit, I will see scroll events like this (rounded slightly):

```
scroll x: -352 scroll y: -373
scroll x: -4 scroll y: 3
scroll x -4 scroll y: 3
```

The first value of the scroll is always a huge jump that I'm not remotely performing with my finger I'm scrolling with. It seems like it's treating my first scroll motion as if I moved my finger from a corner of the canvas to the place the finger actually is?

Here's my actual listener:

```
public class BoardScrollListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private GameService gameService = GameService.getInstance();
    private UiService uiService = UiService.getInstance();

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        Log.d("scroll", "scroll x: " + distanceX + " scroll y: " + distanceY);
        if (distanceX > -150 && distanceY > -150) {
            Game game = gameService.getGame();
            game.setxPixelOffset((int) (game.getxPixelOffset() - distanceX));
            game.setyPixelOffset((int) (game.getyPixelOffset() - distanceY));

            uiService.getGameboardActivity().getGameboard().invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried wrapping it in that if check to see what happened, and that actually fixes the problem most of the time, but it obviously isn't a real solution. Can anyone tell me why the motion event is inaccurate, and a good way to make it accurate or ignore the first motion event of a scroll?

I'm using the v4 support activity fragments, so I also tried switching to `GestureDetectorCompat`, but that doesn't change anything. (This is on a KitKat device.)

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465540/scroll-listener-first-distancey-always-negative-for-downward-scroll

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. In my case I found it was due the fact I'm using onInterceptTouchEvent(). I need this because an ACTION_DOWN event should be handled by a child of my viewgroup. However when intercepting a ACTION_MOVE event and feeding it to a GestureDetector, the MOTION_DOWN event preceding the ACTION_MOVE does not get sent over. In onScroll() of the GestureListener e1 is always null.

In onScroll() the very first distanceX is calculated based on positionX of e1. After that the positionX of the previous e2 is used. If e1 is missing onScroll() uses 0 or the position where ACTION_UP occurred of the previous scroll, if that exists.

Anyway, long story short. To make it work I decided to ignore the first ACTION_MOVE in onScroll(). See below for the code I used.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    // always handel touch event completion
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //Log.i("Intercept Up: ", "END GESTURE");
        mIsScrolling = false;
        return false;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            // Record position
            mDownX = event.getX();
            // let the child handel the event
            return false;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mIsScrolling) {
                // we are currently scrolling, so intercept the event
                return true;
            }
            float dx = event.getX() - mDownX;
            if (Math.abs(dx) > mTouchSlop) {
                // We met the motion threshold; Intercept the event to initiate scrolling
                mIsScrolling = true;
                return true;
            }
            // Not scrolling and threshold not met
            return false;
        }
        default: {
            // other motion events will not be intercepted
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    // always handel touch event completion
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mIsScrolling = false;
        // Used to ignore the first scroll event with bad distanceX
        mIsFirstScrollEvent = true;
        return true;
    }
    // Use GestureDetector to detect event type
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}


private final GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mGestureListener =
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                             float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        // First scroll event should be ignored because of bad distanceX
        if (mIsFirstScrollEvent) {
            mIsFirstScrollEvent = false;
            return true;
        }

        // Do the scroll stuff here

        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First you get coordinates of `ACTION_DOWN` event then later distance. I think that you should do a check for event action.

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

    Log.d("scroll", "scroll x: " + distanceX + " scroll y: " + distanceY);

    // ! CHECK FOR EVENT ACTION !
    if (e2.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Game game = gameService.getGame();
        game.setxPixelOffset((int) (game.getxPixelOffset() - distanceX));
        game.setyPixelOffset((int) (game.getyPixelOffset() - distanceY));

        uiService.getGameboardActivity().getGameboard().invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added a message for whether e2 is an `ACTION_MOVE` to my log line, and it's always an `ACTION_MOVE`. I feel like my issue must have something to do with attaching this GestureListener to a custom view canvas?

Comment: Well, IDK then, but you get these big values on first call of onScroll because e1 is ACTION_DOWN motion event that started the scrolling.

Comment: e1 is always null. Both the events appear to be the same in all circumstances. I only see the distances change.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html See onScroll method - it says that e1 is down event and e2 is scroll event

Comment: I was attaching a normal "onTouch" listener to the custom view. It seems like that was screwing everything up. Putting that listener into `onTouchEvent`, and always returning true from `onTouchEvent` seems to have cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was separately attaching an `onTouch` listener that was causing this issue. Pulling the body of that event into my custom view's `onTouchEvent` overridden listener fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

But in my case I use different OnGestureListener-s for onInterceptTouchEvent(...) and onTouchEvent(...) methods.

Therefore I just set a flag in intercept-listener for ignoring first scroll event passed to actual touch-event-listener

```
private class GestureInterceptListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        final boolean shouldIntercept = ...; // here we decide should we intercept this event, or should it be passed further 
        if (shouldIntercept) {
            mGestureProcessListener.setFirstScrollEventIgnored(true);
        }
        return shouldIntercept;
    }

}


private class GestureProcessListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private boolean ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = false;

    /**
     * For some reason first scroll event on half-visible settings list gets strange incorrect negative values
     * @param isIgnored - should next scroll event be ignored? value resets to false afterwards
     */
    public void setFirstScrollEventIgnored(boolean isIgnored) {
        ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = isIgnored;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent) {
            ignoreFirstBuggyScrollEvent = false;
            return true;
        }
        ... // process scroll event here
        return true;
    }

}
```

Works for me